# Special characters are automatically converted to &#x01 and cannot be assigned to xml variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have lot of data with special characters that are not visible in SQL Server. My problem is, I have a stored procedure which picks this data and converts it into XML, but it is failing because the special characters are convert into `&#x01` and while assigning to a XML variable it is throwing an error:

> XML parsing: line 1, character 70, illegal xml character

Here is my sample code

```
declare @org NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @xm xml

SELECT @org=--'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + 
        CAST((SELECT OrganizationName from organization where OrganizationId=24137603  FOR XML PATH('')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) --AS XmlData
select @org
select cast(@org as xml)
```

I tried including xml version but still no use. This is the output of `@org`

```
<OrganizationName>Some orga&#x01niation name;</OrganizationName>
```

What is the possible way to fix this problem without correcting the data?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365316/sql-server-replace-invalid-xml-characters-from-a-varcharmax-field

Comment: What do you expect? Having an XML code with non-printed characters?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thanks for the link.. I will look into it. SlavaMurygin I want to encode the special characters so that it does not throw the error.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37286755/5089204

Comment: Your `org` output misses a semicolo, but this is not the answer to your question...

Comment: Hi Harsha, is this still open? Do you need further help? If this issue is solved, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. As you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
--This works
DECLARE @NormalSpecialCharacters NVARCHAR(100)=N'ÄÖ€ بو ஆகி';
SELECT @NormalSpecialCharacters FOR XML PATH('test')                       --<test>ÄÖ€ بو ஆகி</test>
SELECT CAST((SELECT @NormalSpecialCharacters FOR XML PATH('test')) AS XML) --<test>ÄÖ€ بو ஆகி</test>
```

The same with *forbidden non-printable* characters will not allow to cast this back:

```
DECLARE @NonPrintableCharacters NVARCHAR(100)=CHAR(0x1) + CHAR(0x2) + CHAR(0x3) + CHAR(0x4);
SELECT @NonPrintableCharacters FOR XML PATH('test')                             --<test>&#x1;&#x2;&#x3;&#x4;</test>
--But it is not allowed to cast this back to XML
--SELECT CAST((SELECT @NonPrintableCharacters FOR XML PATH('test')) AS XML)
```

One workaround: Cast your value to `VARBINARY(MAX)`. SQL Server will implicitly convert this to `base64` and therefore allow all kind of characters. On reading your data you must pick them out with `.value('XPath','varbinary(max)')` to get the implicit reconvert and cast this to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` to get your original string:

```
SELECT CAST(@NonPrintableCharacters AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FOR XML PATH('test')    --base64 encoding! <test>AQACAAMABAA=</test>
SELECT CAST((SELECT CAST(@NonPrintableCharacters AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FOR XML PATH('test')) AS XML) 
SELECT CAST(CAST((SELECT CAST(@NonPrintableCharacters AS VARBINARY(MAX)) FOR XML PATH('test')) AS XML).value('/test[1]','varbinary(max)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```